# Is there a global .bash_profile for all users on a system?

Tags: bash, svn

So I stumbled across [svn color](https://github.com/jmlacroix/svn-color) and thought it was something useful all our devs would appreciate.  The read me for this says to put some code in your `~/.bash_profile`, but I'm wondering how I might include this globally on the server, so it's a default for everyone.  Is there some global `.bash_profile` I could add this to? Perhaps another way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To include commands for all users on your system, use `/etc/profile`.

From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable.

Some distros also read `/etc/profile.d/*` by default, and you can put your customizations there. See http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/profile.d

Answer (score 15):

Already answered, but thought this might be helpful to others looking.

On Amazon Linux `/etc/profile` states:

```
# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.
```

With that in mind, I created a `bash_profile.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`.

In that file, I added `export PS1=" insert_desired_bash_profile_options "`

Don't forget that a logout/in is probably required to pick up the changes.